# Moving CoreData data blob into separate object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am moving a NSData property out of a CoreData object and into a separate object, so `self.pdfData` becomes `self.pdf.data`. Does this look like the right approach to manage creation and deletion of the secondary object?

```
- (void)setPdfData:(NSData *)pdfData
{
    if (!pdfData) {
        if (self.pdf) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.pdf];
            self.pdf = nil;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!self.pdf) {
            self.pdf = [BaseFormPDF insertInManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        }
        self.pdf.data = pdfData;
    }
}

- (NSData *)pdfData
{
    return self.pdf.data;
}
```

Comment: Why are u even saving the binary pdf data into core data ? Write the file to local document directory in app's sandbox and write relative path to file in core data, thats more clear approach I believe

Comment: This is a valid point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good approach.

1) by moving the data to a separate entity you can fetch the main entity without loading the large data into memory.

2) psudo properties on managedObjects is are really cool and work very well for things like this.  But I would be worried about doing too much in a setter.  In this case I think it is OK, but doing more can cause issues.  If a programmer is just setting `thing.pdfData = data` and lots of stuff is happening that the programmer didn't expect that could cause bugs.

Comment: I couldn't see anyway to do less in the setter. Any suggestions of an alternate approach?

Comment: I think what you are doing now is fine.  but it is just a warning to not do too much.